# Border-Shadow and decrease the size of parent element css in cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I have a following image:

[image]

I am trying to add border shadow to the rectangle shape. Is that possible in cytoscape? Also, the parent elements are Customers and order. Can I decrease the size of customers and order parent element?

Here's is the link to the code and the working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpnys1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo_test.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Decreasing the parent size:**

This is a styling issue, cytoscape.js applies padding to parent elements, if you want your parent element to be as small as possible, you'll have to adjust the padding in the :parent style:

```
{
    selector: ":parent",
    css: {
        ...
        "padding": "0px"  \\ remove padding completely, parent almost touching inner nodes
    }
},
```

**Border shadow**

This was a little tricky, cytoscape.js only provides a normal border (like "border": "1px solid black"). You can use these styles:

- border-width : The size of the node’s border.
- border-style : The style of the node’s border; may be solid, dotted, dashed, or double.
- border-color : The colour of the node’s border.
- border-opacity : The opacity of the node’s border.

None of this provides us with the ability to apply a one sided border. As an alternative, I used the [ghost](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/ghost) styles:

- ghost : Whether to use the ghost effect; may be yes or no.
- ghost-offset-x : The horizontal offset used to position the ghost effect.
- ghost-offset-y : The vertical offset used to position the ghost effect.
- ghost-opacity : The opacity of the ghost effect.

If you adjust it a little bit, you can use the x offset and a nice opacity value to achieve this box shadow:

```
ghost: "yes",
"ghost-opacity": 0.5,
"ghost-offset-x": 1
```

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jh99j5?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with both changes applied.